# Remove files that start with but don't contain

Tags: linux, filenames, rm

I'm trying to remove a lot of files at once but need to be specific as to not remove any of the files I actually need.

I have a ton of corrupt files that start **master-** but there are valid files that start with **master-2018**

So, I want to do something like

```
rm -rf master-* --exclude master-2018*
```

Is that I need possible?

Comment: These files sound important. Why not copy/move the `master-2018*` files somewhere else first, and then just remove all the rest?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can use more than one pattern with `find`:

```
$ find -name 'master-*' \! -name 'master-2018*' -print0 -prune |
     xargs -0 echo rm -fr
```

(remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the dry run)

You should add a `-maxdepth 1` predicate just after `find` if you only want ro remove files from the current directory, ie `master-1991` but no `subdir/master-1991`.

Comment: but the OP is using `rm -rf`, `-delete` will only work if the dir is empty.

Comment: I'll give this a go and report back, thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any advantage in using `find … -print0 | xargs …` over a simple `find … -exec` or `find … -execdir`?

Comment: @Sparhawk Efficiency.  `-exec` will start a new process for every hit, while `xargs` will only start one extra process.

Comment: @Sparhawk yes, the fact that `find` and `xargs` are run in parallel. `find ... -exec cmd {} +` (with the `+` at the end) will fit as many arguments as it can to `cmd` (just like `xargs`), but `find` will still have to wait for it to finish before proceeding further. The disadvantage of `find -print0 | xargs -0` is that is not standard -- it's pretty well supported though (GNU, *BSD, busybox, android, solaris if used with gxargs).

Answer (score 10):

In bash:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo rm master-!(2018*)
```

Remove the `echo` if it looks correct.

The above uses bash's extended globbing facility to match files that start with `master-` but who do not have `2018` immediately following, then followed by anything (`*`).

Answer (score 0):

If all files you want to delete has pattern like master-YYYY*, you can use those patterns:

```
rm -rf master-???[0-79]*
rm -rf master-??[02-9]*
rm -rf master-?[1-9]*
rm -rf master-[013-9]*
```

The goal is to ommit digits from a year number, so on first place after master- we need to ommit (don't remove) digit 2, on 2nd place digit 0, on 3rd place digit 1, and on 4th place - digit 8
I tried it just a minute before, and is enough to run only first two of them.

Second method:
You can move master-2018 to another dir, e.g. /tmp,
then remove everything with master-*, and move back your master-2018 from tmp.

```
mkdir /tmp/backup
mv -r master-2018* /tmp/backup
rm -rf master-*
mv -r /tmp/backup/* .
```

Comment: Ahh so, rm -rf master-????[2019-9999]* would remove all files from master-2019* to master-9999*?

Comment: No, it not works this way. You can not specify numbers in [ ] braces. Only digits. You specify which digits will be places in the place of [xxxxxxx]. So max possibilities is range from 0 to 9 like this [0-9] or this [0123456789]. This can replace only one character from file name.
`rob@vps:mast$ ls`  

`master-1990  master-1994  master-2006  master-2010  master-2014  master-2018`  

`master-1991  master-1995  master-2007  master-2009  master-2013  master-2017`  

`rob@vps:mast$ rm master-[2000-2019]*`  

`rob@vps:mast$ ls`  

empty directory`

Comment: none of your commands will remove a file with the name `master-of-puppets`